# getting information about the principal

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I have several methods for a restful webservice with this signature

```
public @ResponseBody SomeObject someMethodSignature(Principal principal){
```

given that it's legacy code, is there a way to get other information from principal (`Principal` is an interface from `java.security` with only one useful method `getName()`) other than the name without the need to pass anything else to the method as parameter? Like permissions and stuff like that?

thanks

Comment: what to rephrase this question so that it makes sense? `principal` is a method argument that is passed when it's called, it's not an object. Did you mean "other than the class name"? If so, yes of course, you can get the class's entire definition by using reflection to obtain the Principal class.

Comment: are you using spring security?

Comment: @Taylor: Yes Taylor, spring-security is in there.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: imho it makes sense. `Principal` is an interface from `java.security` with only one useful method `getName()`. That's not enough information for me, I would like to know about principal's permissions.

Comment: @dierre with that information, sure. So can you update the post to explicitly mention that you know that Principal is the java.security.Principal class, and that there is a security manager being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Spring Security as you say, then the `Principal` object should be an instance of Spring Security's `Authentication` interface. See the [API Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/servletapi/SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.html#getUserPrincipal%28%29).

This means you can cast the principal and invoke the `getAuthorities` method on it, like so

```
((Authentication)principal).getAuthorities();
```

Note that other security-related methods of `HttpServletRequest` are also overridden, so you could also change your method to take a request object and invoke, for example the `isUserInRole` method if that would suit your requirements. This would avoid you having to add any dependency on Spring Security in your classes.

Answer (score 1):

The Principal only carries the name (usualy the login returned by the Authentication infrastructure) there isn't much more info to get. However, you check the [JAAS reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jaas/JAASRefGuide.html) you will see that there are other classes that carry info like the AuthPermission that is used to hold names that identify stuff your Principal is authorized to use and, therefore, we use this to activate (typically) menu options.

Answer (score 1):

The interface Principal doesn't contain many information, but implementations may. As in [Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/realm/GenericPrincipal.html) and [Weblogic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/apirefs.1111/e13941/index.html?weblogic/security/principal/package-summary.html), you can find some more interesting information.